# Angularjs: redraw directive with different template when user logs in

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

in our general layout we have a sidebar which contains a few user details like name and thumbnail. but also a few different things.

we had the idea to load the sidebar with a directive, and inside of that, have 2 templates, 1 when logged in and 1 when logged out.

to display and not display the user details.

however, we have a directive called sidebar working with either of the 2,

App.directive('sidebar', ['UserService', '$compile', function(User, $compile) {

```
var getTemplate = function() {
    console.warn(User.isLogged);
    var templateUrl = "#sidebar" + ((User.isLogged) ? '_loggedin' : '') + "_template";
    console.log('requesting template: [%s]', templateUrl);
    return $(templateUrl).html();
};

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var tmpl = getTemplate();
        element.html(tmpl);
        element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
    },
    template: getTemplate()
};
```

}]);

and we load our user details in a service

```
App.factory('UserService', [function userService() {
var User = {
    isLogged: false,
    username: ''
};
return User;
}]);
```

the login form accepts this `UserService` as dependency, and sets it's `isLogged` to `true`

but how can I let the directive redraw the sidebar, when the `isLogged` is changed?

are we doing this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a stage known as the compile phase where angular

> walks the DOM to identify all the registered directives in the
>   template. For each directive, it then transforms the DOM based on the directive’s
>   rules (template, replace, transclude, and so on), and calls the compilefunction
>   if it exists. The result is a compiled templatefunction, which will invoke the link
>   functions collected from all of the directives.

Basically, you can't conditionally load templates - it will compile the first one you give it. If you want to dynamically render your view, you might use two divs with the ng-show directive inside the template:

```
<div ng-show="user.isLogged">// logged in content</div>
<div ng-show="!user.isLogged">// logged out content</div>
```

You might think you need to inject a factory into your directive - I have just tried this and it does not work! I believe this is because directives can only set up one and two-way binding's with those on the scope chain. With that in mind, I brought the user object into application wide scope:

```
App.controller("AppCtrl", function($rootScope, UserService) {
  $rootScope.user = UserService;
})
```

And then used an open scope from the directive:

```
app.directive("sidebar", function() {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: '<div>' +
      '<div ng-show="user.isLogged">Logged In</div>' +
      '<div ng-show="!user.isLogged">Logged Out</div></div>',
  }

})
```

The user object here is being found through scope chaining. Because the directive does not have an isolated scope (I haven't declared a scope property), it is finding it through the scope chain - right up to the root scope. This is of course a "global" in a sense, and could easily be hidden:

```
$scope.user = somethingElse
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it does the job.

You could also conditionally manipulate the DOM in the link function, or better yet - off load this kind of logic to the router making use of nested templates and resolve.

Comment: This seems fine, another option might be ng-include where the templateURL is changed.

Comment: I've tried your solution, however am not convinced of the outcome, the problem is, that the loggedin version, for example has an avatar of the user, if i have it's src attribute on `src="/images/users/{{user.avatar}}"` it doesn't matter if the show displays it, it gets rendered, meaning it will throw a 404 when the user.avatar property is undefined

any idea how to tackle such a thing?

Comment: You should check out ngSrc: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngSrc :)
Should take care of nulls and will properly parse directives.

Comment: If your img is nested inside a block level element with ng-show, it shouldn't render. ng-show just works by setting display to none. If it isn't doing what you want then it is a problem with your markup/css.